# tkinter: checkbutton is not working

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I tried to make a checkbutton which is supposed to activate a function "rond" but it's not working... What have I done wrong ?

```
from tkinter import*

def rond():
if okok.get()==1:
    print("ok")


okok = BooleanVar()
okok.set(0)
root = Tk()
can = Canvas(root, width=200, height=150, bg="light yellow")
can.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", variable=okok, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=rond)
can.pack(side="top")


root.mainloop()
```

After it has run this appears:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/PycharmProjects/untitled/testtest.py", line 7, in <module>
    okok = BooleanVar()
   File    "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.   py", line 389, in __init__
   Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)
   File    "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 233, in __init__
   self._root = master._root()
   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems:

1. The exception you are getting is because you have to create `root = Tk()` before the `BooleanVar`.
2. As already noted, you should use the [`Checkbutton`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/checkbutton.html) widget instead of `Canvas`. The `command` then goes directly into the constructor; no `bind` neaded. Also, your `onvalue` and `offvalue` are the same as the default, so those are not really needed, either.

   ```
   can = Checkbutton(root, width=20, height=15, bg="light yellow",
                     variable=okok, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=rond)
   ```
3. Without an image icon, the `width` and `height` will be in characters (i.e. lines and columns of text), so the numbers you entered are much too high. Alternatively, provide an image icon.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using canvas and not the check button. I would try something like this:
cbutton = Checkbutton(root, etc, etc)

or check out effbot.org for a good resource.